# Windows Mobile 10: Saving files on a remote file share (SMB/CIFS)

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, uwp

I understand why Microsoft has limited the functionality of IO operations on the UWP platform, but I figure that this functionality must exist.

The requirements are:
1.Connect to remote file share via URI (eg. \servername\share\sub-folder)
2.Authenticate using remote server credentials
3.Get a filestream (storage file) to this location to write my new file

Could anyone provide either a link or a brief C# example that shows how I could go about doing this please?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the FileSavePicker class?

```
var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker();
var storageFile = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
```

Comment: Yes it only works on tablets though, on phone network shares are not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found while this is possible for UWP apps, that is only when they are running on tablets or above. UWP apps on phones simply do not support SMB shares.